# Correct implementation of AES 128 encryption with initialization vector and padding

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, aes

I implemented AES 128 bit encryption using initialization vector and padding, as seen in the code below. I happen to be using ColdFusion, but I don’t think that matters. The encrypted result shows some repeating patterns, which I would not have expected, but then again I don't know the characteristics of correct output for this. Am I doing initialization vector and padding correctly?

```
<!---
To encrypt this, for example:
    "String1"
Prefix the string with an Initialization Vector of 16 random characters,
plus enough padding ("000000001") to make the entire string a multiple of 16 characters (32 characters, here)
    "HoMoz4yT0+WAU7CX000000001String1"
Now encrypt the string to this (64 characters):
    "Bn0k3q9aGJt91nWNA0xun6va8t8+OiJVmCqv0RzUzPWFyT4jUMzZ56pG5uFt6bGG"
--->

<cfoutput>

    <cfset EncryptKey="LpEecqQe3OderPakcZeMcw==">

    <cfloop index="StringToEncrypt" list="String1,String2,String3,String3">
        <!--- Make random Initialization Vector (IV) of length 16 
        (create it from GenerateSecretKey(), but GenerateSecretKey is NOT the key that we encrypt/decrypt with) --->
        <cfset IV=left(GenerateSecretKey("AES",128),16)>
        <!--- Pad the string so its length is a multiple of 16 --->
        <cfset padlength=16 - (len(StringToEncrypt) mod 16)>
        <cfset padding=repeatstring("0",padlength-1) & "1">
        <cfset NewStringToEncrypt=IV & padding & StringToEncrypt>
        <cfset EncryptedString=encrypt(NewStringToEncrypt,EncryptKey,"AES","Base64")>
<pre>Original string: #StringToEncrypt#
StringToEncrypt: #NewStringToEncrypt#
EncryptedString: #EncryptedString#</pre>
    </cfloop>

</cfoutput>
```

Below is sample output:

```
Original string: String1
StringToEncrypt: QLkApY6XKka7mQge000000001String1
EncryptedString: BOAVeSKidQyyHrEa15x9Uava8t8+OiJVmCqv0RzUzPWFyT4jUMzZ56pG5uFt6bGG

Original string: String2
StringToEncrypt: DboCmHHuVrU05oTV000000001String2
EncryptedString: 4Yk14F0ffz9+djbvSiwA1/X3FHhS5Vhta7Q8iocBPhmFyT4jUMzZ56pG5uFt6bGG

Original string: String3
StringToEncrypt: 8om5VbbWQgvRWK7Q000000001String3
EncryptedString: 01AF+pmF9sDsUHcIXSVfom8Egv8Oiyb2yy12hiVcJjqFyT4jUMzZ56pG5uFt6bGG

Original string: String3
StringToEncrypt: T4qJodVe6aEv0p1E000000001String3
EncryptedString: aAjCbSBRZ+cd7ZwpFPZUxW8Egv8Oiyb2yy12hiVcJjqFyT4jUMzZ56pG5uFt6bGG
```

Each EncryptedString ends with the same 21 characters:

```
FyT4jUMzZ56pG5uFt6bGG
```

When the original string is the same ("String3" in the 3rd and 4th example), the EncryptedString ends with the same 42 characters:

```
8Egv8Oiyb2yy12hiVcJjqFyT4jUMzZ56pG5uFt6bGG
```

**Update:** Per the accepted answer, I should not do my own padding or initialization vector. Coldfusion's encrypt/decrypt functions can handle that automatically, and the encrypted values will have no repeating patterns. For example:

```
EncryptedString=encrypt(StringToEncrypt, EncryptKey, 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding', 'Base64')
DecryptedString=decrypt(EncryptedString, EncryptKey, 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding', 'Base64')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do *not* do your own padding, but let the encrypt function do it. It's *appended* to the plaintext, not prepended. The usual padding is called PKCS5 padding and adds $t$ times the byte $t \in {1,2,3,\ldots,16}$ to make up full blocks.

Also, the iv is an argument to the encrypt function and not prepended before the plaintext. It's actually (when you use a chain-mode like CBC, OFB, CFB) prepended to the ciphertext.

So you could generate the IV as you do (though there are probably better functions to do it) and then use the plaintext as is and encrypt:

`EncryptedString=encrypt(StringToEncrypt, EncryptKey, 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding', 'Base64', binaryDecode(IV, "base64"))`

(based on [this documentation](https://cfdocs.org/encrypt))

**added 2**
The iv should be binary according to these docs, so the base64 from generateKey has to be converted. Thx to comments by @Agax and his "cftry" examples...

**added 1** It turns out that omitting the IV will cause the function
to generate its own IV, and in a seemingly non-repeating way. 
In any case we can use

`EncryptedString=encrypt(StringToEncrypt, EncryptKey, 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding', 'Base64')`

instead. It's essential to use a chaining mode like CBC to get the propagation effect from a random IV that masks identical plaintexts and which the default 'AES' leaves visible (this does ECB mode, presumably).

The IV is actually not prepended to the ciphertext, when we give it as an argument, so you have to remember it somehow to be able to decrypt the first block of plain text. Quite non-standard. When you let encrypt generate it itself, it does prepend it. So you have to use the same signature version of decrypt.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer for me. In your code snippet, I could not get the IV parameter to work satisfactorily, but through additional research, I found that your code snippet without ", IV" adds an initialization vector by default (and of course, PKCS5Padding adds padding), and there are zero repeating patterns in the encrypted results. If you edit your answer to remove ", IV", and to explain that an IV is added by default, then I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @FlanMan the docs suggested that you could provide your own IV (but it has to be "binary data", and you used base64 encoded data, so maybe that's an issue?). It probably randomly generates an IV (it's important they're unpredictable) if you omit it.

Comment: @Ageax He wasn't using PKCS5 padding even. You should also no padding in that gist, just use the original input strings. I saved a new simpler version.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma - Yes, technically he was, whether or not padding was needed because ECB and PKCS5Padding are the default in CF.  But gah.. you're right about the input. Pasted the wrong gist again on my mobile!  Here's the correct link https://trycf.com/gist/d8bb46669a0a152c0562cb8a9a0f5a1e/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: @Ageax why doesn't CF accept the key as binary after binaryDecode(encryptionKey, "base64"), it says AES key 2 bytes (which it is not, it's 16 after decoding)...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma - What code are you using? Maybe one too many binaryDecode()'s? Both the manually generated IV and encryptionKey should work, as they're both 16 bytes (encoded as base64). **Edit** https://trycf.com/gist/3e230be823d188ce0f674864f1b13b8a/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: @Ageax It seems that encrypt *expects* the encryptkey to be base64, because generateKey("AES", 128) gives a base64 string back and so that's the standard input format for AES keys but the IV should be binary for sure. Thx for thinking along.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma - Yep. Keys must always be in "base64", and iv's in binary (and "plain text" is always handled as utf-8). Always thought the implementation was a bit weird. i.e. Why not require base64 for both key/iv? But *shrug*, no changing it now I guess.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason for this is that the mode of AES you are using doesnt use the previous block with the current block before encrypting the current block.

For example, CBC mode performs an XOR with the previous block cipher text and the current block plaintext before encrypting the current block. This means that even with the same string ("string3") and same key, a different IV will yield a completely different result, and there will never be string repetition.

Other modes of AES that use XORs include: CBC, PCBC, OFB, CFB. This  [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)  describes the different modes of AES in more detail (under the "common modes" section).

Comment: Note too that the base64 encoding is performed for each iteration in the loop, and 16 is definitely not a multiple of 3 (3 bytes are encoded as 4 characters after all).